# Robot odometry calculation On uC or on pc

Tags: first-robotics

I need to do odometry calculations but I'm contemplating where I should do it. I'm using a core i5 6th gen mini pc with 8Gb ram so it's plenty strong for a robot brain but my issue is with the communication between it and my micro which is an f407 discovery. Using a mini pc has locked me out of any PCIe mesa card interface and researching on USB I found out it can have up to a 65ms delay worse case when transferring/receiving data. Which just leaves ethernet (I can't do that because my Uc doesn't have a DMA channel for ethernet).

So after finding all that out, My next idea was to just let the Robo brain tell my uC where to go and the uC does all the odometry calculations and sends an acknowledgement back to the brain when it has reached the desired position.

My uC will be responsible for reading some sensors, 2x1000c/r encoders, 2x motor control, battery management etc. I think it can handle it...I think.

Is this a reasonable approach or should I try something else?

Answer (score 1):

It's common to do the encoder reading and low level odometry calculations at lower levels in microcontrollers. As well as for battery management and motor control as those things require very low latency updates. And if you can then integrate the results locally and forward their abstracted output periodically to the higher level computer that's a common approach.

There will be tradeoffs for how much computation you can do in the microcontroller both what algorithms you use and how you implement them, as well as how much bandwidth to spend on communications, trading off throughput and latency etc. But I would suggest going ahead with your approach and for your application just like every other one there are likely to be specific tradeoffs that you'll have to learn to balance.